# Display all posts for taxonomy term across multiple custom post types

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, page-template

I'm currently creating a website that uses several content types, (e.g. books, movies, shows) as well as a key taxonomy term (e.g. status, with values of owned and wishlist).

My question is, in a custom template how do I create a loop that queries only one taxonomy value across multiple custom post types (i.e. a single list of all of the books, movies and shows on my wishlist.)

The closest I could find was this post [Using Query Posts With Multiple Post Types And A Taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50035/using-query-posts-with-multiple-post-types-and-a-taxonomy)

But unfortunately, I am having a hard time making it work as is in my template. And, ideally I'd prefer to use a wp_query instead of get_posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an array of post types and a tax query for your term. The question you linked had special requirements as only one of the post types used the taxonomy.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'books', 'movies', 'shows' ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'wishlist'
        )
    )
);
$wishlist = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Of course I massively overcomplicated that problem. Worked like a charm. Thanks!