# WP_Query get post from a category and from another post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have 2 post types (post and help). In post (post type), there is a category named "Hello" and I want to get all posts from the category "Hello" (post_type = post and category_id = 2) and all posts from the post type "help" with a uniq WP_Query.

This doesn't work:

```
$categoryId = 2;
$page = get_query_var('paged', 1);
$post_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page', 10);
$params = array(
    'post_type' => array('help', 'post'),
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'cat' => $categoryId,
    'paged' => $page,
    'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

$q = new WP_Query($params);
```

Comment: What do you mean by This doesn't work? Do you get any error/no result?

What is the exact issue?

Answer (score 1):

A good way could be the one explained [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50035/using-query-posts-with-multiple-post-types-and-a-taxonomy)

Basically you get the different queries results separately, assigning them to two different variables, merge the two result sets into array, getting the IDs of all this combined arrays, and last.. querying by IDs

```
$args1 = array(
  'post_type' =>   'help',
  'post_status' => 'publish'
  )
$args2 = array(
  'post_type' =>   'post',
  'cat' => $categoryId,
  'post_status' => 'publish'
)
$help_posts = get_posts( $args1 );
$post_posts = get_posts( $args2 );
$combined_query_array = array_merge ($help_posts, $post_posts ); //merge
$post_myneeded_IDs =  wp_list_pluck( $combined_query_array, 'ID' ) //squeeze IDs out
$desidered_query = get_posts( array(
  'post__in'    => $post_myneeded_IDs,
  'orderby'     => etc. etc
));
```

update, following the comments.. using 'fields' => 'ids'

```
$args1 = array(
  'post_type' =>   'help',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'fields' => 'ids'
  )  //now get_posts() will return just a collection of IDs
$args2 = array(
  'post_type' =>   'post',
  'cat' => $categoryId,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'fields' => 'ids'
  )
$help_posts_ids = get_posts( $args1 );
$post_posts_ids = get_posts( $args2 );
$combined_posts_ids = array_merge ($help_posts_ids, $post_posts_ids ); //merge
$desidered_query = get_posts( array(
  'post__in'    => $combined_posts_ids,
  'orderby'     => etc. etc
));
```

Comment: You can use the `'fields' => 'ids'` in `get_posts()` to only fetch the ids and to skip the `wp_list_pluck()` part.

Comment: yes, far more elegant :)